# Cant delete Azure Database

Tags: azure, database, sql, azure-sql

Created this a database from a backup.

I want to delete this database because I selected the incorrect backup. When trying to delete the database I get the following error:

Failed to delete the database: [DBNAME].
ErrorCode: 400
ErrorMessage: Cannot use reserved database name '[DBNAME]' in this operation.
This is an SQL database.

Steps taken to delette database:

1. Open Azure Portal.
2. Select Database ([DBNAME]).
3. Click delete button.
4. Get above mentioned error.

[image: Error]

[image: Error]

Connecting with SSMS: The Database that I want to delete is not there
[image: DB not there]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285775/how-to-deal-with-sql-column-names-that-look-like-sql-keywords

Comment: @ceejayoz Is that really related here? (his question implies he was using the Azure GUI)

Comment: Have you tried deleting the database using [SSMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)? The GUI isn't always reliable and if you keep getting the error you'll either want to contact support, or try a manual deletion using SSMS. Btw if you can could you add some screenshots about your error? I'd like to see where you get this message.

Comment: @Reaces Given the error message, it appears the GUI isn't escaping the database name, and that OP has used a reserved word as a name. Relevant, but doesn't fully answer, hence my comment.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.
I am connecting to the server through SSMS, but the database that I want to delete is not there. Only my Live DB shows. I've added a screenshot.

Comment: @ceejayoz I just thought it made no sense that Azure let him create a database with a reserved name, restore it, but then not delete the restored database. And indeed, the database name itself does not look like it is a likely reserved name. In stead something else is going wrong here.

Comment: @LouwrensPotgieter I would really suggest you contact microsoft support for this. You have a database in the GUI that isn't showing up in SSMS, that shouldn't happen.

Comment: @LouwrensPotgieter yeah you really need to raise a support request with MS, something is broken if that's not showing in SSMS.

Comment: Thank you all. Ill put in a support request to Azure. The worst of the matter is, they are charging me for this database ;)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have used a reserved word in the DB name and for some reason the deletion process in the Azure portal isn't dealing with this. A couple of ways to deal with the immediate issue:

- Delete the database through SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)
- Use SSMS to rename the database to something without a reserved word and then delete it through the portal

I would also suggest raising an bug with MS as the portal should either handle this, or prevent you from creating the DB in the first place.

Comment: +1, I should have put that in an answer myself :)

Comment: Hi - i have the same problem (im using SSMS by default) - however the problem database is not listed under the database server's node in SSMS